# Balance Check if brackets are closed in a string using stacks

Tags: java

I am writing a program that would check to see if sets of brackets are closed in a user-inputed string, but I am confused about how to do it because we need to use stacks to accomplish it.

My idea is to add the brackets to the stack if they exist, then if a closing bracket shows up, pop off the top TWO characters from the stack and if the second popped off character matches the first (as in type of bracket matches and it is both an opening and closing bracket) then the line is balanced. However, I need to have it be able to work for strings with multiple brackets and characters in them, for example:

```
 wfsfs[{{{(s;dkls(dslkf)s;dlkf}]}]}}}sd
```

I am really confused about how to make this work using stacks! Any ideas?

Here is basically the code I came up with so far but it doesn't work with multiple brackets

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        if (x.charAt(i) == '('){
            stack.push('('); 
            }
        if (x.charAt(i) == '['){
            stack.push('(');
            }
        if (x.charAt(i) == '{'){
            stack.push('(');
            }
        if (x.charAt(i) == ')'){
            stack.pop(); 
            if (stack.empty()){
                return true; 
                }
            if (stack.pop() != ')'){
                return true;
                }
            }
        if (x.charAt(i) == ']'){
            stack.pop(); 
            if (stack.empty()){
                return true; 
                }
            if (stack.pop() != ']'){
                return true;
                }
            }
        if (x.charAt(i) == '}'){
            stack.pop(); 
            if (stack.empty()){
                return true; 
                }
            if (stack.pop() != '}'){
                return true;
                }
            }

    }

    return false;
}


}
```

edit: "x" is an inputed sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is my thought. You could push an open bracket onto the stack (and only push when you have an open bracket), then pop whenever you have a closing bracket. If you are unable to pop because there is nothing on the stack, the test fails. If you get to the end and there's something on the stack, the test fails.

This gets harder if they have to be paired (i.e. {{}{}{}} is a failure not a success), but then you could just track that once you start popping if you push again you fail.

EDIT: If you have to match one of the three kinds of "brackets" (technically you have brackets, curly brackets, and parentheses) then you could have three different stacks, or validate with peek that the top "bracket" on the stack matches the closing one.

EDIT2: to show a pseudocode example:

I have a string: "[[]]"

Scanning through the string, I see my first character is a open bracket [   I pop this onto my stack, making my stack 1 item large with '[' on it.

My next character is also an open bracket, so I pop this onto the stack as well, meaning I have 2 items on my stack, '[' and '['

the third character is a closed bracket.  I peek on the top of my stack, and see it matches the open bracket that is there, so I pop the open bracket off the stack, leaving me with one open bracket on the stack '['

my fourth character is a closed bracket.  I peek on the top of my stack and see that it matches the open bracket that is on the stack.  I pop this bracket off my stack, leaving me with an empty stack.

I end my string, see I have an empty stack, so this passes.

Edit3: example with different brackets.

Say I have a string : "[{(){}}]"

My first character is a '[' so I pop it onto the stack

My second character is a '{' so I pop it onto the stack

My third character is a '(' so I pop it onto the stack

My fourth character is a ')', so I check the top of the stack with peek.  it is a matching paren '(' so I pop it off the stack and move on.

My fifth character is a '{' so I pop it on the stack.

My sixth character is a '}' so I peek at the top of my stack, see a matching '{' and pop it off the stack.

My seventh character is a '}' so I peek at the top of my stack, and see the matching '{' so I pop it off the stack.

My eight character is a ']' so I peek at the top of my stack and see that it is a matching ']' so I pop it off the stack.

I reach the end of my string and have nothing left on my stack, so I am good, and the case passes.

Comment: Oh hmm now i'm thinking maybe i could have separate stacks then measure the amount of items in each stack and if it divides by two evenly then it is a pass

Comment: Not neccesarily, you want to use the push and pop mechanic.  I could have {{{{  and it would pass if I just check dividing by two

Comment: oh you're right good point. Hmmm but how would I get the push and pop to work if for example the series was something like [[]] where if I pop the top one it will not be a matching bracket?

Comment: would I just have to make a brand new stack for each new set of brackets and count how many stacks are left?

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHH i'm sorry I misunderstood before, your edit clarified I'll give that a shot! thank you!

Comment: The only thing this doesn't solve is if the first brackets are close brackets, it remains empty and therefore true. Maybe i could do something like "if close bracket -> if empty return false" do you think that will have any problems?

Comment: As I mentioned, you probably want to have a fail condition if you have a close bracket and the stack is empty, or the top bracket doesn't match the close bracket